# 1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' Error wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm triying to import my SQL to the new Wordpress hosting but I get this error:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_afp_items` (`item_id`, `item_title`, `item_link`, `item_description`, `item_client`, `item_date`, `item_thumbnail`, `item_image`, `item_category`)
VALUES (1, '??????', '', '?????????', '?????', '2015-01-23', 'http://kleaz.com/demo/lop/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/31.png', 'http://kleaz.com/demo/lop/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/2014-09-11_111208.jpg', '');
```

> #1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Your `wp_afp_items` table already has some records in it. You need to make it empty before importing

Comment: Just go to phpmyadmin and empty table

Comment: Hold on, what's that table? Does it come from a plugin or is it a custom table of your own? It doesn't look like a cache table so you shouldn't empty it like that.

Comment: I fixed problem with this way ; I just deleted all db and create new one, without any wp table, then imported sql backup. All is working.